# Sum using wildcards in Google Data Studio?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I am working with a column that either has a 4 digit number, or a 4 digit number followed by a letter (A,B, or C). I am trying to get a count of all records where there is the number and alphabet combination. How can I get a count of these records using wildcards? I used this formula to count of records ending with just A, but it appears to be invalid.

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(OP_Number, '(*.A)') THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Formula 1: COUNT Letters

This formula performs a [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207) of the number of values with 4 *Numbers* followed by a *Letter* `\\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}`:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(OP_Number, ".*(\\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}).*") THEN "Count Letters"
    ELSE NULL END)
```

**Note**: The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) above allows for flexibility, thus change the number(s) in each respective section based on the requirement (zooming in on the [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) function to elaborate):

```
REGEXP_MATCH(OP_Number, ".*(\\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}).*")
                                ^          ^
                             Change     Change
                             Numbers    Letters
```

#### Formula 2: SUM All Values

The formula below uses the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) function to capture 4 digits `\\d{4}`, then turns the *Text* field to a *Number* field using the [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) function, and ends by aggregating the field by [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212):

```
SUM(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(OP_Number, "(\\d{4})") AS NUMBER ) )
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ae5742db-3ee3-4716-9c17-9222262be0ad) to demonstrate.

[image: 8]